# Trying to get property of non-object ( Codeigniter )

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am getting an error "Message: Trying to get property of non-object"
when i try to display slider from database.

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>   Filename: home/index.php
>   Line Number: 78

From admin side , admin enters slider name , image and Description and
it will display on user side at home page

At localhost (using wamp) it is working perfect but when i will upload online , it is giving error

**Home.php ( Controller File )**

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) 
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home/index');
    }
}
```

**Index.php  ( View File )**

```
<div class="body_resize">
        <div class="body">
            <div class="border_box">
                <div class="box_skitter box_skitter_large">
                <?php
                     $info=$this->dbcommon->getInfo(array('homepage_image'),'homepage',array('status'=>0),'1','','sort_order');
                     foreach($info as $row)
                     {
                         print_r($row); 
                         ?>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img  src="<?php echo homepage.'medium/'.$row->homepage_image ?>"  class="cubeHide" alt="8_abs.jpg"
                                        width="900" height="400" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                     <?php
                     }?>

                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="js/jquery.skitter.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    var options = {};

                    if (document.location.search) {
                        var array = document.location.search.split('=');
                        var param = array[0].replace('?', '');
                        var value = array[1];

                        if (param == 'animation') {
                            options.animation = value;
                        }
                        else if (param == 'type_navigation') {
                            if (value == 'dots_preview') {
                                $('.border_box').css({ 'marginBottom': '40px' });
                                options['dots'] = true;
                                options['preview'] = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                options[value] = true;
                                if (value == 'dots') $('.border_box').css({ 'marginBottom': '40px' });
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $('.box_skitter_large').skitter(options);

                });
            </script>
            <div class="body_home">
                <h4><strong>Welcome to Softloopers!</strong></h4>
                                <?php $info=$this->dbcommon->getInfo('','master','','','0,1','');
                                echo $info->homepage;

                ?><br />
            </div>
```

**getInfo  function**

```
function getInfo($field_name='',$table_name,$array='',$return="",$limit='',$orderby='')
    {
        if($field_name=='')
        {
            $sql='select * ';
        }
        else
        {
            $str='';
            foreach($field_name as $row)
            {
                $str.=$row.',';
            }
            $str=rtrim($str,',');
            $sql="select ".$str;
        }
        $sql.= ' from ' .$table_name .' where 2>0 ';
        if($array!='')
        {
            foreach($array as $key=>$value)
            {
                $sql.="and $key='$value' and";
            }
            $sql=trim($sql,' and');
        }
        if($orderby!='')
        {
            $sql.=" order by $orderby"; 
        }
        if($limit!='')
        {
            $sql.=" limit $limit";
        }
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if($return=='')
        {
            return $query->row();
        }
        else
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
    }
```

Comment: where this `getInfo function` define ??

Comment: You cant write codes on view. Use controller to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data to view from controller, you can do like this

**Home.php ( Controller File )**

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) 
     exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller 
  {
     public function index()
     {
        $data['info']=$this->dbcommon->getInfo(array('homepage_image'),'homepage',array('status'=>0),'1','','sort_order');
        $this->load->view('home/index');
     }
  }
```

**Index.php ( View File )**

```
<div class="box_skitter box_skitter_large">
            <?php

                 foreach($info as $row)
                 {
                     print_r($row); 
                     ?>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <img  src="<?php echo homepage.'medium/'.$row->homepage_image ?>"  class="cubeHide" alt="8_abs.jpg"
                                    width="900" height="400" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                 <?php
                 }?>

            </div>
```

Comment: In your controller do print_r($data['info']) and check if you are getting values

Comment: not getting any value.  It just disply "Array ( ) " at the top of the page

Comment: That is why you are getting this error. You are not getting any data from database. Do you have data in that master table?